# Looping Dynamic Memory Allocation C++

Tags: c++

I'm having issues using malloc to allocate memory using a for loop for a homework assignment. Below is the code for my constructor which takes in a char array and a char pointer array and returns the number of tokens in the char array.

The constructor should go through the char array, skip to the first character that is not empty (the beginning of the first token), then print the index of that char. It should then find the next empty character in the string (the end of the token), and print its index. After doing so, it computes the number of characters in the token and uses malloc to allocate memory in the pointer array. I was told to use memcpy by my professor to copy the token into the pointer array. The program then prints the pointer array. Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int parseCommandLine(char cline[], char *tklist[])
{
    int lineLength = strlen(cline);
    int tknCount = 0;
    int tknStart;
    int tknEnd;
    int tknLength;
    int tknIndex;
    bool check;
    cout<<cline<<":"<<lineLength<<endl;
    if(cline[0]==0)
    {
        check = false;
    }
    else
    {
        check = true;
    }
    for(int j=0; j<=lineLength; j++)
    {
        if (isspace(cline[j]) == false && check==false)
        {
            cout<<j<<endl;
            check = true;
            tknStart = j;
        }

         else if(j==0 && check==true)
        {
            cout<<j<<endl;
            tknStart = j;
        }
        else if (check==true && (isspace(cline[j]) || j==lineLength))

        {
            cout<<--j<<endl;
            check = false;
            tknCount++;
            tknIndex = tknCount - 1;
            tknEnd = j;
            tknLength = tknEnd-tknStart;
            tklist[tknIndex] = (char *) malloc(tknLength +1);
            memcpy(tklist + tknIndex,cline + tknStart, tknLength);
            cout<<tklist<<endl;
         }
    } 
    cout<<"There are "<<tknCount<<"tokens in this line.\n"<<endl;
    tknCount = 0;
    return tknCount;
}
```

When running the constructor, it is correctly identifying the endpoints of the tokens, but it is printing only the first memory location, which makes it seem as if the malloc is not accepting the loop. It is very strange, please help if you can.

**Edit**: Here is a simple `main()` based on comment:

```
int main ()
{
    char * out[6] = {0};
    char cline[] = "new_sensor_node SN42 42 3.57 5.0 7";
    parseCommandLine(cline, out);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output of running this:

```
$ ./a.out 
new_sensor_node SN42 42 3.57 5.0 7:34
0
14
0x7fffd3762c70
16
19
0x7fffd3762c70
21
22
0x7fffd3762c70
24
27
0x7fffd3762c70
29
31
0x7fffd3762c70
33
33
0x7fffd3762c70
34
There are 6tokens in this line.
```

Note that the same address is printed for each iteration.

As requested, here is the input code

```
ifstream infile;
char line[MAX_CMD_LINE_LENGTH] = {0};
char *tokenList[MAX_TOKENS_ON_A_LINE];

int main()
{
infile.open("p4input.txt", ios::in);
if(infile.fail())
{
    cout<<"The input file has failed to open. Program will now terminate."<<endl;
    return 0;
}
else
{
    infile.getline(line,MAX_CMD_LINE_LENGTH);
    parseCommandLine(line, tokenList);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
}
```

In headers

```
#define MAX_CMD_LINE_LENGTH 256
#define MAX_TOKENS_ON_A_LINE 30
```

Comment: I don't see any `constructor` in your code. Can you include sample input and output in your question? this would help more understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you provide some sample input, with the output you expect and the output you actually get.

Comment: How are you calling this method? What arguments are you giving to it?

Comment: the cline input would be a char array containing this test input:
new_sensor_node    SN42    42  3.57  5.0    7.
The output should look like this:
new_sensor_node    SN42    42  3.57  5.0    7.:46
0
14
(memory location)
19
22
(memory location)
...
soo on and so forth listing out all of the first and last indexes for the tokens and their corresponding memory locations

Comment: There are too many issues with this code, but here are two questions for you. (1) You have allocated some memory and put its address to `tklist[tknIndex]`, and at the very next line you are trying to fill memory at `tklist + tknIndex`. Don't you think there is some kind of discrepancy here? (2) You print `tklist` in a loop. `tklist` never changes. What do you expect to be printed out?

Comment: Ideally, in the end, I would be displaying the actual tokens themselves, but when I try to do that with a line such as: cout<<tklist[tknIndex]<<endl; I get an error saying Unhandled exception at 0x5151d51c (msvcr100d.dll) in assignmentFour.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x5f77656e.

Comment: @user2481270: can you provide the code that is calling `parseCommandLine`

Comment: TO n.m.
I admit I am a bit confused on the use of memcpy, but from a few pages I found online I gathered that to change the index to which I am copying the token to, I should increment it like I have in the code. If that is incorrect please let me know. 2. Am I not changing tklist when I use memcpy to copy memory into its indexes?

Comment: Here is the code that is calling parseCommandLine: I'm not sure how to format this for you, I apologize in advance. 

    ifstream infile;
char line[MAX_CMD_LINE_LENGTH] = {0};
char *tokenList[MAX_TOKENS_ON_A_LINE];

int main()
{
 infile.open("p4input.txt", ios::in);
 if(infile.fail())
 {
  cout<<"The input file has failed to open. Program will now terminate."<<endl;
  return 0;
 }
 else
 {
  infile.getline(line,MAX_CMD_LINE_LENGTH);
  parseCommandLine(line, tokenList);
  system("pause");
  return 0;
 }
}

I have the system pause so I can read the output

Comment: @user2481270 You can click the `edit` button underneath your question. There you can add formatted code, sample output, etc.

Comment: Did the code I added help anyone see what my problem might be? I know the code most likely has quite a few flaws, but it's really the best I know how to do at this point in time.

Comment: The memcpy(tklist + tknIndex,cline + tknStart, tknLength); line is wrong..  @n.m. gave you a clue.  Currently it will trash the stack.

Comment: @Pete Is there any way you could elaborate on why it will trash the stack so I can get a little better understanding of how it is operating?

Comment: I believe I have fixed part of the issue, as I have changed the memcpy statement to this: memcpy(tklist[tknIndex],cline + tknStart, tknLength); But when I am trying to print the tokens, I get garbage code after the tokens on the line

Comment: (1) Yes that line is wrong. You need to forget those pages and start over. (2) No you are not changing tklist (you are not copying memory to its indexes either, see (1), but even if you did it would not change tklist). You are confused about pointers and pointer arithmetic. That's not "a bit", more like "totally".

Comment: I appreciate you coming back just to insult me, without even reading where I said I believed I had fixed my main issue. Can you confirm that the line written in the comment above your last looks alright?

Comment: You are almost there. Just solve the garbage problem. You have allocated `tknLength +1` bytes, but copied just `tknLength` bytes. The extra byte is needed, but you have not used it correctly. You have to figure out why it's needed and what to do with it.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that I need to somehow find a way to store the null character at the end of the token?

Comment: Yes that's correct, you need the null character. You are still printing `tklist` which doesn't change. You need to print a string you have just created.

Comment: So you're saying I need to call the string itself with something like cout<<tklist[tknIndex]<<endl, or are you saying I should not be calling to tklist at call it?

Comment: Yes `cout<<tklist[tknIndex]<<endl` should do it

Comment: @user2481270 The reason it was trashing the memory was because `tklist + tknIndex` gives you the address of the element at tknIndex not its value.  Its *value* is the pointer to the string that you `malloc`d.  Using array syntax is equivalent to `*(tklist + tknIndex)` not `tklist + tknIndex`.  On re-reading your code it may not actually be the stack that is trashed since your array is a global variable.  I'm not sure where the compiler actually puts that memory but it is corruption nether the less.

Comment: OK now that you have sorted it out, I have to say that in C++ we normally use std::string and std::vector, not manually allocated arrays. You should learn these tools if you want to use C++ for real (a school assignment may require you to use pointers and such, that's OK for didactic purposes).

Comment: Additionally if you `malloc()` something, you should generally `free()` it somewhere - in the same way that if you `new` something you should `delete` it.  Failing to do so is generally a memory leak.  It's kind of OK if you only allocate it once for the run of the program as your process heap will be freed up at exit however it is bad practice to do so.  std::string and std::vector do this for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

`tklist` is an array of pointers. On line

```
tklist[tknIndex] = (char *) malloc(tknLength +1);
```

you are assigning a pointer to an element of the array `tklist[]`. The `tklist` itself is not changed! only its elements are assigned value.
Therefore, when you do `cout<<tklist<<endl;` the `tklist` always prints the address it is pointing.

Another thing on your main program `*tokenList` is not initialized, so it is pointing an arbitrary address (0x7fffd3762c70).

I suggest you should allocate memory for `*tokenList` once in your main() before calling `parseCommandLine(line, tokenList);` and only print `cout<<tklist+tknIndex<<endl;` in `parseCommandLine()`.